# DevDemon Forms: The Forms Module requires jQuery 1.3 or higher. (jQuery not found)

Tags: error, jquery, devdemon, devdemon-forms

I recently upgraded a site from EE2.5.4 to EE2.9 and upgraded Forms from 3.3.1 to 3.4.11

On the old version of the site, forms were storing in the dashboard & sending the relevant emails to admin & user. Since the upgrade I get the error:

**The Forms Module requires jQuery 1.3 or higher. 
(jQuery not found)**

whenever I load a page with a form on it & the form doesn't save or send. I'm not seeing the success message either.

has anyone come across this & fixed it before?

Answer (score 1):

The version of forms that I updated the site to has a tag that does all of this for you. http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/output-javascript/ explains it all. Always helps to read the docs.

Added  queue_js="yes" inside my forms tag & then added {exp:forms:output_js} just after I called jQuery at the bottom of my page.